# Is Azure the right choice for hosting my ASP.NET web application to deliver Data Visualization?

Tags: asp.net, azure, analytics, saas, paas

I am starting an Analytics company that analyses my clients data, holds the results of the analysis on a server, and allows my clients to access the results and view charts and graphs using an ASP.NET web application I have written.  Each client would obviously have access to their own web application by signing in with their secure password.

Is Azure the right choice for delivering this kind of service?  Does it host my SQL Server license?  Does it scale for many users who EACH need their own version of the web application?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Q: Is Azure the right choice for hosting my ASP.NET web application to deliver Data Visualization? A: Microsoft would certainly say "Yes" ;)  I can't think of any reason why not.  Be aware the the Azure version of MSSQL is significantly different from "standard" SQL Server.  If you encounter problems, your next best bet would probably be a Windows-Server VPS (for example, from 1&1): http://www.1and1.com/vps-hosting

Comment: I wonder why the Windows-Server VPS shall be from 1and1 but not from Azure again - the Azure Virtual Machines - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "EACH user will need their own version of the web application"? You mean just their own version of data maybe? (you can edit the question to add clarifications)

Answer (score 2):

These are some good links I used when I was getting familiar with Azure. I hope they will help you too.

[Intro to Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/other/fundamentals/intro-to-windows-azure/) - Please read this entirely.

[How to use Azure in SaaS](http://www.notsotrivial.net/blog/post/2012/05/30/Windows-Azure-Recipe-Software-as-a-Service-%28SaaS%29.aspx) - This is how it looks in action.

It seems like here you are talking about multi tenant application. Azure is very good platform for this kind of applications. You can utilize cool features like SQL Azure federation and SQL Reporting when building your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Websites and SQL Azure should be able to handle this pretty well.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. To add further clarification....EACH of my clients would need to access their own web app which would display THEIR organizations data.  But this basic web app template would be very similar for all my clients...just different graphs and visuals since each client's data and analysis results will be different.

Comment: Also...what is the difference between Azure and Windows-Server VPS?  I am with Bizspark and would like to take advantage of their free MS development tools and whatever they offer for hosting.  That is why I am asking about Azure (offered through Bizspark).

Comment: If you run an Azure VM, there is no difference, but you are fully responsible for patching the server, doing antivirus scans, etc. If you use one of the Azure Managed services (such as Azure Websites, which will work for your app, to use Azure Web Services you need to use the correct Azure visual studio template)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on how much traffic you've estimated you're going to get AND how much data you're going to generate.

If it's business intelligence analytics like I'm thinking of it would probably be better to setup your own local Hadoop cluster and web servers.